# Add-Member to Az object

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm writing a function that I can use for thumbing through all my subscriptions in azure and gather environment details (for auditing or bulk updating) and I'm trying to append the subscription the item came from into the return object so I can keep things sorted. This is the beginning of the function I'm building:

```
Function Find-AllAzResourceByType
{
    Param (
        [ValidateSet('SqlServer','KeyVault')]
        [String]$type
    )
    ForEach($Subscription in (Get-AzSubscription))
    {
        Set-AzContext $subscription.Name | out-null
        Switch ($type)
        {
            "SqlServer" {$return += Get-AzSqlServer | Add-Member 'Subscription' $subscription.Name}
            "KeyVault" {$return += Get-AzKeyVault}
        }
    }
    Return $return
}
```

I have tried several ways of calling the add-member:

```
Get-AzSqlServer | ForEach {$_ | Add-Member 'Subscription' $subscription.Name}
Get-AzSqlServer | ForEach {Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Subscription' -value $subscription.Name -inputobject $_}
Get-AzSqlServer | Select-Object *,$Subscription.Name
```

and nothing I'm trying seems to work. I'm sure this is something obvious I'm missing but I'm failing to see it... anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Your `$return` variable is empty because it has not be declared before `foreach` loop, declare it as `[array] $return = $null` before `foreach` loop and it should work

Comment: not sure I understand the comment here. If I null out return before the foreach loop it will not return me a master loop. The point of this function is to return back every azure object of a specific type for every subscription I can access, then append each subscription name to each of the objects (since when I append them, I no longer know which subscription context I need to be in)

Comment: Instead of adding the subscription property, can't you extract it from the resource id? Essentially each resource id follows the following naming convention: `/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name/<resource-type>/<resource-name`.

Comment: *facepalm*... thank you! that is what I was looking for. add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're interested in is finding about the subscription id of the resource, you don't really need to do all of this. You can extract the subscription id from the `ResourceId` property.

When I execute `Get-AzSqlServer` against my Azure Subscription, for each SQL Server I get the resource id in the following format:

`/subscriptions/<my-subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<my-resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<my-database-server-name>`

I can easily parse the above string to get the subscription id.